# How to get reliable U.S. state responses by reverse geocoding?

Tags: api, maps, reverse, reverse-geocoding

Google sometimes returns the incorrect U.S. state when reverse geocoding a lat/long.  Presumably this is because Google is trying to return the nearest street address, which in some cases is not in the same state as the lat/long you are trying to reverse geocode.

Though it may not be a common scenario in practice, it's pretty easy to reproduce by playing around with a map: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/reverse.html

For my application, I am less concerned about getting the nearest address and more concerned about always getting the correct U.S. state for a lat/long.  Is there a way to achieve this with Google's API?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all results and pick the one with `"administrative_area_level_1"` in `results[i].types`

This is better than taking the "equivalent" address component from the first result, i.e. finding `"administrative_area_level_1"` in `results[0].address_components[j].types`

When reverse geocoding snaps your latlng to the nearest address which happens to be in a different state (or country), the state/country address component of the first result will be that of where that address is, but the subsequent result will be the state/country where the input latlng is.

Example: 42.834185,-0.302811 is in Spain, but snaps to an address in France.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D42.834185%252C-0.302811

```js
results[0].address_components[3].types = ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
results[0].address_components[3].short_name = "FR"
results[6].types = ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
results[6].short_name = "ES"
```